# Informatica: How to replace TRUNC(DATE) in informatica so that PDO works?

Tags: teradata, informatica

I have date in this format `09/27/2017 15:42:07.000000` but i want my `DATE` to be like `09/27/2017 0000:00:00 or 09/27/2017`.

I tried this already :

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR('09/27/2017 15:42:07.000000', 1, 20),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

it won't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you give more details? Are you trying to export this date in a flat file? Are you looking at it in the debugger and want it to look differently? Where are you reading from, writing to and what are the data types in these systems'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

`TO_CHAR('09/27/2017 15:42:07.000000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')`

`TO_DATE` is for taking a non date field and telling informatica what the incoming format is so it knows how to format it in a date format.

I've not tested but you could also try

```
GET_DATE_PART('09/27/2017 15:42:07.000000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```